# Laravel 4 login redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I do not want to show login page after login in laravel 4. If a logged in user want to visit login page it should redirect to homepage('/'). I am using Sentry for authentication.

filter.php

```
Route::filter(
    'auth', function () {
    if (!Sentry::check()) {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', function() {
return View::make('login');
}))->before('guest');

Route::post('login', 'AuthController@postLogin');
```

AuthController.php

```
function postLogin() {
    try {
        // Set login credentials
        $credentials = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

        // Try to authenticate the user
        $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
        if ($user) {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    } catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException $e) {
        return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors('Login field is required');
    }
}
```

After successful login if, if login page is requested it still shows the login page

Comment: Show your `guest` filter, please.

Comment: its laravel's default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Laravel's default `guest` filter, it will not work, because the default `guest` filter does not check if your Sentry user is logged in.

Try this instead:

```
Route::filter(
    'filter', function () {
    if (Sentry::check()) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

In your routes.php, the filter is already being applied to the login route, so things should work this way.